# Chrome extension with Ghostery-like alert

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I create popup like in Ghostery and is it possible to have some HTML content in it?

[Ghostery's purple bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly4Xb.jpg)

Comment: ghostery's alert isn't an alert.  Right click on it and inspect it. You will notice it is simply just an element appended to the page you are on.

Comment: You are right. Quite nice workarond, but still I have no idea how to acomplish this :/

Comment: My greatest mistake when creating my extension was to not read the documentation(which resulted in a lot of frustration and complete code re-writes).  You can read the documentation about content scripts here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts , about message passing here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging , and of course the getting started course here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted .  By the time you are done reading, you'll know what to do.  Good luck ;)

Comment: I know the pain ;) I've make 70% of extension and then I realise that I cannot implement some essential for my addon feature ;)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to implement a notification popup for a Chrome app or extension is to use the **chrome.notifications** API. You can choose to enrich the notification with a text or even an image, but HTML content is not supported. Find the complete documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications

Comment: I know about this, but I need HTML :/